# Is BackUpDutyLite Malware?

Tags: malware

My teacher's laptop has a program called BackUpDutyLite. She says that she might have installed it, but possibly not. A google search shows some examples of it being malware, but I am not sure. Is it malware?

Comment: I would say _Yes_ from looking at the google search for "BackUpDutyLite".

Answer (score 3):

BackupDutyLite simply appeared as an icon on my PC desktop.
I don't know if it is MALWARE or what it is.
I simply wanted to GET IT OFF MY PC and here is how to do it.

1. click on START
2. click on CONTROL PANEL.
3. click on ADD OR REMOVE PROGRAMS
4. look alphabetically for BackupDutyLite
5. click on it and it will turn blue
6. click REMOVE.
7. It will completely disappear, when you shut and restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

It is malware. Donot install it in any way. It is destructive.
Perhaps scan with superantispyware and that should get rid of it.

Moses